# Independence in Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X \thicksim B(n,p)$ then show that

$E[X(X-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(X-r+1)] = n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-r+1)p^r ,\;r = 1,2,...n$

---

To prove above statement, I had chosen to prove below claim first

**claim** : $X, X-k$ are independent when $k = 0, 1,...r-1 $

First I had used the property $E(X\cdot X-k) = E(X)\cdot E(X-k)$ but had realized that it is necessary condition of independence not sufficient.

Then only I have to do is to derive joint pdf of $X, X-k$ then compare it to multiplication of marginal ones.

How could one derive joint pdf of $X, X-k$?

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X=x_1,X-k=x_2) = P(X=x_1)\mathbb{I}(x_1=x_2+k) = \binom{n}{x_1}p^{x_1}(1-p)^{n-x_1}\mathbb{I}(x_1=x_2+k)$$

**Edit**: Note that the above joint is not equal to $P(X=x_1)P(X-k=x_2) = \binom{n}{x_1}\binom{n}{k+x_2}p^{x_1+k+x_2}(1-p)^{2n-x_1-k-x_2}$

So, $X, X-k$ are not independent.

Now, the right way to obtain the result is,

$$E(t^X) = \sum_{x=0}^{n}t^x\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x} = (tp+1-p)^n$$

$$E(X(X-1)\ldots(X-r+1)) = \frac{\partial^r E(t^X)}{\partial t^r}\bigg\vert_{t=1}$$

Answer (score 0):

A ``probabalistic'' argument:  You have $n$ items, which are independently marked with probability $p$ each.  The number of marked ones is $X$.
For each $k$-element subset $S\subseteq [n]$  let $I_S=1$ if all elements of $S$ are marked, $0$ otherwise.  Then $\binom X k = \sum_S I_S$, where the sum extends over all $\binom n k$ subsets of size $k$. Now evaluate $$E\,\binom X k = \sum_S E\,I_S = \binom n k p^k.$$ Multiply both sides by $k!$ and you have your result.

Comment: thx. I love ggakdduki too.

Answer (score 0):

For measurable functions $f$ and a discrete rv $X$ it holds $$E[f(X)] = \sum_{l=0}^n f(l) P(X = l)$$ hence we get by simple calculation
$$\begin{align*} E[X(X-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(X-r+1)] &= E\left[\frac{X!}{(X-r)!}\cdot1_{\{X \ge r\}}\right] \\ &= \sum_{l=r}^n \frac{l!}{(l-r)!}\binom{n}{l} p^l (1-p)^{n-l} \\ &= \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}p^r \sum_{l=r}^n \frac{(n-r)!}{(l-r)!(n-l)!} p^{l-r} (1-p)^{n-{l-r}} \end{align*}$$
Substituting $k=l-r$ gives us:
$$\begin{align*} E[X(X-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(X-r+1)] &= \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}p^r \sum_{k=0}^{n-r} \binom{n-r}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \\ &= \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}p^r \cdot 1 \\ &=  n(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(n-r+1)p^r \end{align*}$$